# Will disk cloning resolve bad stripes on RAID?

Tags: windows, raid, ibm, clone, acronis

We have a logical RAID1 drive in bad stripes state, which kept that status even after replacement and rebuilding of both drives, and gives errors in Windows logs about failure of writing to disk.

IBM support suggests erasing and re-creating the RAID, then re-installing the Windows.

The resulting down-time unacceptible for us, so we want to clone the RAID (via Acronis True Image), erase and re-create the RAID, then dump the cloned data back. Following IBM logic where RAID erasing and re-creation resets the whole RAID meta-data, this should clear the bad-stripes status, and start from a blank page.

Question is if such strategy is possible, and will produce the desired effect?

Any idea is appreciated - thanks in advance!

Comment: i would do a chkdsk /R before to ensure data are corrects. You could also check if disks have bad sectors (and so reallocated sectors count). This counter is available through smart report on standard disk. For example on my blog i had issue on a disk (windows raid, not hardware one, so tool see physical disks): http://www.lotp.fr/2010/05/a-tous-ceux-qui-ont-des-disques-de-1to-sans-raid/
I would check if the ibm server raid tool allow to get these numbers. Maybe one or both are just dying.

Comment: The both drives are brand new, and replaced after subsequent drive failures we had. Ran chkdsk /r several times - says all fine, but RAID1 still reports bad stripes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work fine. I had a VERY similar problem where windows was experiencing file system errors. I cloned the drive, blasted the array, recreated it and restored the image and everything has been perfect since then. My question was [HERE](https://serverfault.com/questions/106844/bizarre-file-system-errors-sbs2003).

Comment: Just wanted to update it worked as charm, no bad stripes anymore :).